Компьютерные корпуса или корпусы?
Как же правильно?
Напомню, что человеческие ко́рпусы (тела), но военные корпуса́ и корпуса́ у дома под каким-то номером.

Давненько не пересекались, Артём! Э-э... Не поняла: корпусы́?

Привет, Рим! Да нет, ударение, конечно, не на Ы!))

Мне кажется корпусА, корпусЫ у живых объектов, одушевленных, а у вещей или др системных понятий корпуса. Наверное разные слова: corpus, corpse/body - смотря живое или нет.

А где лайк, Рим?)

Подходит  КОРПУС 2. мн.: корпусА, -ов и корпусы, -ов. Основа, остов или оболочка механизмов, ПРИБОРОВ, аппаратов и т.п. К. скрипки. К. самолёта. Часы в золотом корпусе.  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=корпус&mode=slovari&dicts[]=71&dicts[]=42

Шарон, спасибо большое, а где же лайк?)))

Извини, Артем, совсем забыла...)  Лайк от меня!

Спасибо большое!! Уже не только от вас)))

Я бы даже два лайка поставила, но не получается)  Вопрос действительно интересный.

О, очень рад, Шарон, что вам нравится, спасибо большое!)))

✿ Русское словесное ударение
корпус, -а; мн. корпуса́, -ов (здание; войсковое соединение; учебное заведение; остов, оболочка чего-либо); корпуса предприятия; стрелковые корпуса; кадетские корпуса; корпуса часов.
✿ Большой универсальный словарь русского языка
● 2.0. мн. чаще корпуса́. Основа или оболочка механизма, прибора, аппарата и т. п., на которой или в которой монтируются другие детали.
✿ Большой толковый словарь русского языка
2. мн.: корпуса́, -ов и ко́рпусы, -ов. Основа, остов или оболочка механизмов, приборов, аппаратов и т. п.
Если ориентироваться на эти словари, то получается, что лучше говорить компьютерные корпуса́. Я бы выбрала именно этот вариант.
✿ Дополнительно — мнение "Грамоты":
№ 235744
как правильно писать "корпуса компьютеров/машин/агрегатов" или "корпусы компьютеров/машин/агрегатов"?
Ответ
Правильно: корпуса.
P. S. Но — вот совершенно другое решение, изложенное в русском орфографическом словаре:
ко́рпус, -а, мн. -ы, -ов (туловище; шрифт; остов, оболочка; совокупность кого-либо, чего-либо).
Какой же словарь главнее? Или, может, где-то неточность?
КОРПУС

И лайк есть, Артём, и даже цветочки.

Спасибо большое, Рим! Какие такие цветочки?)))

Цветочки? В тексте ответа — первый раз использовала. Аж четыре штуки. Думала как-то разнообразить...

Ахахах, понял теперь, о чём ты, прикольные цветочки. :))

Из комментария Sharon: Но в орфографическом словаре написана совершенная муть, которая не соответствует другим словарям. Вот это и надо было написать. К сожалению, я не языкознатель и не филолог, поэтому так четко и, главное, корректно не решилась изложить в своем ответе. Как обыкновенный, простой любитель смогла только вот так, по-дилетантски: может, где-то неточность? Конечно же,  это очень неаккуратно с моей стороны.

Грамматическая справка

Основным окончанием для существительных м. рода 2-го склонения на твердый согласный является окончание Ы по образцу стол — столы.

Окончание А является вариантным, но встречается часто: город — города. Это окончание заимствовано из 2-го склонения для сущ. ср. рода: озеро — озера, поле — поля, там оно основное.

Различаются два окончание по стилю или семантике. Для слова корпус различие по семантике. Пример стилевого различия: ШТОРМ, -а; мн. штОрмы, -ов и (проф.) штормА; также тракторы и трактора, слесари и слесаря.


Большой универсальный словарь русского языка
 КОРПУС, -а, мн. корпус|ы и корпус|а, м., нд., I а.
 ● 1.0. мн. корпусы. Часть тела человека от шеи до ног, а 
 ткж. часть тела животного от шеи до хвоста.   Син. 
 <туловище о человеке>, тело, <торс о человеке, стан о 
 человеке>. К. лошади. Податься вперёд всем корпусом. Его 
 окликнули, он повернулся к нам всем корпусом. На скачках 
 лошадь из местной конюшни обошла фаворита на два корпуса. ● 
 
 2.0. мн. ЧАЩЕ КОРПУСА. Основа или оболочка механизма, 
 прибора, аппарата и т. п., на к-рой или в к-рой монтируются 
 другие детали. (гр. сокр. кор.) Пластиковый к. барометра. 
 К. скрипки. К. самолёта. Часы в золотом корпусе.

P. S. Добавлю полезную ссылку на слова, где приходится делать выбор между окончанием А и Ы. Впрочем, их желательно проверять по словарю (нормы могут меняться).
Морфологические нормы

Спасибо и вам за ответ! Отлично, что все сходятся на одном и том же!

Да, мы здесь все хором) Спасибо за голос.

Да что ж вы ругаетесь!.. Убрал приоритет (он просто был, потому что я выбрал ответ, ещё когда он был единственным), только не ссорьтесь, пожалуйста. Вроде же Римма нормальный вопрос задала (как относиться к этому мнению)...

Артем, я всем довольна, в том исле вашим решением. Все прекрасно! Мой ответ – это дополнение по грамматике, не более того,безо всяких претензий. Там единственное предложение, которое не устроило участника, вот оно "Я не нашла разночтений в словарях, везде для корпусОв приборов окончание А".   Оно и было мне предъявлено, зачем так написала.  Потому что так считаю и не собираюсь менять свое мнение. Но я его удаляю из ответа,  только бы все успокоились. Просто неловко перед вами.

Зачем нужна грамматика? Чтобы  делать разумный выбор и понимать, что мы выбираем, в чем причина вариантности окончаний. Не всем это, конечно,  нужно, но кому-то пригодится.  Если разрешены два варианта, то чаще всего основное окончание Ы является нейтральным, а вариантное А разговорное или профессиональное. Но в приведенном примере выбор делается по семантике, и важно разделить и как-то противопоставить эти значения, а не смешивать их. Уже в комментариях это противопоставление было обозначено.

Так скажите, пожалуйста, хоть мне, Шарон, как вы думаете, то, что в орфографическом словаре множественное для "корпуса" со значением "остов, оболочка" даётся с окончанием Ы, это другое мнение или они забыли уточнить, что именно в этих случаях должны быть другое окончание и ударение? И в Большом толковом словаре, если верить Римме, тоже есть оба варианта для множественного числа в этом значении. Что об этом думаете?

Надо уметь читать словари и рекомендации Грамоты, ну и основы грамматики знать. Ы - основное окончание, но используется оно практически только для туловища человека,  а все остальные варианты имеют вариантное окончание А, что вполне логично.   Это разделение по семантике. А @Римма  сама делает для вас выбор и говорит, какой вариант ей кажется лучше. // Но в орфографическом словаре написана совершенная муть, которая не соответствует другим словарям. Вот это и надо было написать. Наилучший вариант у Морковкина, который говорит, что  чаще А.

У Кузнецова  А на первом месте, а Ы на втором. Особого противоречия нет. Грамота говорит, что только А, и правильно говорит.  В Сети продают исключительно корпусА компьютеров. Так стоит ли нам сомневаться и думать о том, какой словарь главнее. Думаю, что не стоит, и задача нами однозначно решена. Надо учитывать практику письма, а также анализировать и сравнивать словари.  Надо понимать, что мы делаем семантический выбор, так что желательно разделить варианты на две части.  Вот такой ответ был бы правильным. А когда там отражено КОЛЕБАНИЕ,то приходится дописывать грамматику.

Чем нехорош орфографический словарь? Тем, что там тоже деление вариантов на две группы, как бы по семантике.  Но странная семантика: в одной группе корпуса домов и воен. корпуса, а в другой все остальное (тело человека и вся механика и т. д.). Где логика?

Полностью согласен с вами, Шарон. Вы заметили, что Римма говорит, какой вариант ей кажется лучше, но ведь она тоже стоит за вариант с А и это хорошо. И я теперь буду уверенно говорить о компьютерных корпуса́х. Вам обеим спасибо большое!

Все прекрасно,  Артем, не беспокойтесь. И следуя вашим советам,  я решила ни с кем не ссориться.  Я буду добрей, полюблю я людей, как у Чуковского)  Я, конечно, и раньше их любила, но как-то очень абстрактно, без нужной конкретики) И  даже знаю секретный способ, как это сделать.

Великолепно, Шарон! Очень хорошее решение! и прекрасно, что знаете способ!!
